# Kable forces my table above my text in R, how do I fix this?

Tags: r, markdown, bookdown, kable, rnotebook

I am working on the following code with some latex (making a reproducible report document in R notebook, but for some reason my table is put above my text and equation. How do I fix this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ1Kq.png)

```
title: "Empirical Research in Finance"
subtitle: "**Hypothesis tests and simulation**" 
author: Faes E.
fontsize: 12pt
date: '*January 25, 2021*'
output: 
    pdf_document: default
    html_document:
    df_print: paged
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{color}
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=4in,height=4in]{AMSLOGO.jpg}\LARGE\\}
  - \posttitle{\end{center}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

```
# copy the R logo to the current directory
file.copy(file.path(R.home("doc"), "html", "AMSLOGO.jpg"), '.')
```

```
\newpage

\newpage
```

An examination of the first and second moments of the sample skewness is been done in table 1. There can be seen that the mean goes to zero for larger samples. For the variance, the asymptotic variance is being reached. We know that it should render the following values (equation 2) as we know that skewness is asympotitcally distributed with mean 0 and variance 6/n (where n is in this case the sample size).

````
\begin{equation} 
\tag{2} 
skewness \stackrel{a}{\sim}N(0,\dfrac{6}{n})
\end{equation}

```{r echo=FALSE}
kable(des(mom=S), digits= 3, caption = "Statistics for skewness") %>%
    kable_classic(full_width = F) %>%
     footnote(number = c("n is the sample size","std is the standard deviation"))
```
````

Comment: That's where LaTeX is putting it.  Where do you want it?  See https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-floats for a discussion of what's possible.  One `kable`-specific thing:  if you don't add a caption, your table won't be a float at all.

Comment: @user2554330 it should be under my equation from LaTeX. But for some reason (if you click the image) it is above my text.

Comment: Skip the caption.

Comment: @user2554330 exactly, works then. But now my table title is gone.. What do you recommend

Comment: You can use `kable(..., format = "latex", position = "h!")` to give a very strong suggestion to leave it in place.  If LaTeX thinks that's a bad idea, it still won't do it.

Comment: This did it for, me thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like user2554330 answered correctly and worked for me:

You can use `kable(..., format = "latex", position = "h!")` to give a very strong suggestion to leave it in place. If LaTeX thinks that's a bad idea, it still won't do it.

Comment: Thanks @martin to fix the anser